# Display Images Between Text retrieved from server [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, image, nstextattachment

I want to use NSTextAttachment to display images in between text where the text and images are both retrieved from the server. I have hosted the sample JSON of the text that I want to display. The position where the image needs to be displayed is marked with “[IMAGE]” between the text and links of the image to be displayed is available in the JSON as well.

```
for para in newsText{
    if(para == "[IMAGE]")
    {
        print("Image Found")
        let paraImageLink = images[self.imageCount]["link"] as? String


        let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
        downloader.downloadImage(with: URL(string:paraImageLink!)!, options: .none) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value): let paraImageResized = self.ResizeImage(value.image, targetSize: CGSize(width: 500.0, height: 300.0))
            let imageAttachement = NSTextAttachment()
            imageAttachement.image = paraImageResized
            let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachement)
            self.content.append(imageString)
            self.content.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\n"))
            self.imageCount+=1

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        //
    }
    else{
        self.content.append(NSAttributedString(string: para+"\n\n"))


    }
```

The issue I am facing is that the images are not being displayed at all.

The full code and sample project is available at: 
https://github.com/dnawarrior/textAttachment

The JSON that is used to retrieved the data is hosted at:
https://www.npoint.io/docs/5ab45880fc3dd8c41671

Comment: Is it necessary use NSTextAttachment. Why? Can you use another instruments?

Comment: First, It will help you more if you create a simple project and put the code in question in it, people can modify it and update the code. Second, you'd be better download your images first then use them to create the attributed string. Lastly, for merely downloading a few assets from the internet do not use third party libraries, make your own helper, it makes your final app be smaller and run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ,after the image has downlowned

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.text.attributedText = self.content
}
```

---

I think it is a web image.

```
 let imageURL : URL = URL(string: url)!
```

Developers seldom fetch the image from `url` directly. It is synchronous and hangs the main thread.

We usually download it with `URLSession`, and decoded in background thread, then  renders in the main thread.

[KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) is a good option.

---

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
downloader.downloadImage(with: url) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        print(value.image)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

from [Kingfisher Downloader](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#user-content-downloader)

Comment: I tried it but it still won't show the images between the text. What I am trying to do involves displaying images between text. I want to asynchronously attach the image in between the text even when the image is loading.